# Remove email address from string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string

I have the following code which is supposed to be removing a particular email address from a string if it exists. The problem is i get the error "invalid range "y-d" in string transliteration (ArgumentError)" which I assume is because it's treating my input as a regex. I will need to do this delete by a variable in the actual code, not a string literal but this is a simplified version of the problem.

So how do I properly perform this operation?

```
myvar = "test1@my-domain.com test2@my-domain.com"
myvar = myvar.delete("test1@my-domain.com")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
myvar = "test1@my-domain.com test2@my-domain.com"
myvar = myvar.gsub("test1@my-domain.com", '').strip
```

Answer (score 2):

String#delete(str) does not delete the literal string `str` but builds a set out of individual characters of `str` and deletes all occurrences of these characters. try this:

```
"sets".delete("test")
=> ""

"sets".delete("est")
=> ""
```

The hyphen has a special meaning, it defines a range of characters. `String#delete("a-d")` will delete all occurrences of a,b,c and d characters. Range boundary characters should be given in ascending order: you should write `"a-d"` but not `"d-a"`.

In your original example, ruby tries to build a character range from `y-d` substring and fails.

Use String#gsub method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
myvar = "test1@my-domain.com test2@my-domain.com"
remove = "test1@my-domain.com"
myvar.gsub!(remove, "")
```